# How to finish joint of cement board

Tags: cement-board

When cement board meets a block is expanding metal sufficient to put over the joint to stop it cracking before I scratch coat?

And do I need to put scrim on the joints of the cement board as well as expanding metal?

Comment: Meets a block of what, exactly?

Comment: picture please.